# How can I see heatmap in Piwik?

Tags: plugin, user-engagement, matomo

I have installed and activated the [ClickHeat](https://plugins.piwik.org/ClickHeat#description) plugin in Piwik. But I can't see any heatmap data in Piwik dashboard.

Please see the below images.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Perhaps a Piwik forum would get a faster and more knowledgeable answer

Comment: Plugin website does not providing any data to setup the plugin.

Comment: You can find the setup guide here: https://developer.piwik.org/guides/heatmap-session-recording
If you are still having issues, ask on the piwik forum (https://forum.piwik.org/) or open a ticket on https://shop.piwik.org/tickets/

Comment: Update: I thought you were using the official Piwik Heatmap plugin (https://www.heatmap-analytics.com/), for which my comment would be valid.

Comment: I am using a third party plugin called ClickHeat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Plugin you are using is a third-party plugin and therefore not supported by the piwik team.
According to [this github issue](https://github.com/piwikjapan/plugin-clickheat/issues/26) the plugin isn't compatible with Piwik 3.

As it seems like the plugin isn't maintained any more, I'd recommend you to look into [the official heatmap plugin](https://www.heatmap-analytics.com/), which does the same and even more.